# Adobe Illustrator: make a gradient ellipse over shape and cut everything outside

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, vector, gradient

How can I make an Ellipse with gradient on separated layer, and remove everything, which is not in shape, located on another layer?

I will describe it on a schema, like I do this in Photoshop (example):

1) I create an object, for example a text. Then I create an ellipse selection, that i want to fill later with gradient:
[image]

2) Then I make a gradient, inside this ellipse
[image]

3) As a result I get:
[image]

4) Then on a text layer a make a selection & revert it, so I can later remove everything, that is outside my text:
[image]

5) Then I click delete on a gradient layer - and gradient, that is outside my shape (text) - is removed. As result I have a nice text, with a good gradient, that will not cause any issues, if I change my background.
[image]

And that's the problem with AI. How can i do the same in Adobe Illustrator?
For example I have such two objects on two layers, and want to add a gradient on both of them (ellipse), and later cut everything in this gradient, that is outside my layer. Is it possible to do? And how?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After making the ellipse and the text:

- Outline the text from **Menu Type** > **Create Outlines**
- Select the text and the ellipse
- Using the **Shape Builder Tool** and pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> to delete, click once on the area of the ellipse outside the text
- Select the new shapes > **Menu Object** > **Compound Path** > **Make**
- Apply a **Radial Gradient** and modify the gradient shape using the **Gradient Annotator**

[image: gradient]

[image: FINAL]

Comment: 'Create Outlines' - is disabled (My text is a custom shape... not a text in AI)

Comment: ok, skip that step.

Comment: cool! it works!